# Can't get counter for Java to work

Tags: java, counter

I am new to programming and I can't get the counter to increment or store the grades for each do while loop. The program is suppose to take in grades for the homework then average it, then take in grades for the quizzes then average it, and the same for the tests and finally average the 3 averages together at the end.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Homework3 {

    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int number1;
        int totalhomework = 0;
        int counterhomework = 0;
        double averagehomework = 0;

        String name;
        int homeworkgrade = 0;
        int totalquiz = 0;
        int counterquiz = 0;
        double averagequiz = 0;

        int quizgrade = 0;
        int totaltest = 0;
        int countertest = 0;
        double averagetest = 0;
        int testgrade = 0;

        double finalaverage = 0;
        boolean run = true;

        do {
            System.out.print("\nEnter 1 to average grades for new student");
            System.out.print("\n Enter 2 to quit");
            number1 = input.nextInt();
            if (number1 == 1) {
                System.out.println("\nWhat is the student's name?");
                name = input.next();
            }
            if (number1 == 2) { 
                System.out.print("\nThank you");
                System.exit(1);
            }
            counterhomework = 0;
            totalhomework = 0;

            do {
                counterhomework++;
                totalhomework = totalhomework + homeworkgrade;
                System.out.println("\nFirst enter Homework grades then type " +
                    "-1 to move onto next category"
                );
                homeworkgrade = input.nextInt();
            } while(homeworkgrade != -1);

            if (homeworkgrade == -1) {
                System.out.print("\nYour Homework average is:" + 
                    averagehomework
                );
                averagehomework = totalhomework/counterhomework;
            }
            do { 
                counterquiz = counterquiz +1;
                System.out.print("\nNext enter quiz grades then type -1 " +
                    "to move onto next category"
                );
                totalquiz = totalquiz + quizgrade;
                quizgrade = input.nextInt();

            } while (quizgrade != -1);

            if (quizgrade ==-1) {
                System.out.print("\nYour quiz average is:" + averagequiz);
                averagequiz = totalquiz/counterquiz;
            }
            do { 
                countertest = countertest +1;
                System.out.print("\nFinally enter test grades then type " +
                    "-1 when finished"
                );
                totaltest = totaltest + testgrade;
                testgrade = input.nextInt();
            } while (testgrade != -1);

            if (testgrade == -1) {
                System.out.print("\nYour test average is:" +averagetest);
                averagetest = totaltest/countertest;
            }
            System.out.print(name);
            System.out.print("final average is:" + finalaverage);
            finalaverage = 0.25 * averagehomework + 0.25 * averagequiz +
                0.50 * averagetest;
        } while (number1 != 2);
    } //main
} //class
```

Comment: What problem or exception you got?

Comment: Please clean up the your code before you post on SO. There is way too much white-space and the tabs do not follow the nested structure of your application.

Comment: And there's also a fair amount too much code.

Comment: Please give example input with actual and expected output.

Comment: Does this compile? Name does not seem to be initialized in all cases...

Comment: @user2814798. Welcome to SO. As for your formatting issues, never use tabs for formatting code on SO. It doesn't go well. Follow 4 whitespace indentation rule.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that your problem is the `averagehomework= 0.0` , and this is because you print `averagehomework` before you calculate it , so make it :

```
averagehomework = totalhomework / counterhomework;
 System.out.print("\nYour Homework average is:" + averagehomework);
```

---

you need to initialize the name variable , like this :

```
String name = "";
```

---

the `counterhomework` need to initialze by `-1`